# How can we use Photoshop CS5.1 on Mac OS X Lion in a normal behaving window (like it used to be)?

Tags: osx-lion, adobe-photoshop, fullscreen

I'm new to Mac, but I'm sure I've seen Photoshop windows behaving the way it does in Windows. Where the entire application resided in a single window.  And inside the application window, there could be several other windows for each open file.

The way it is now, the application sort of "attaches" itself to the desktop, so I can't move it to another screen and resize it, etc.

Is it possible to change the behaviour back to the old way?  If so how?

By the way, Illustrator and Indesign work the same way.  I'm hoping the same solution works for these other products also.

Answer (score 2):

Select `Window > Application Frame` to contain everything within a resizable window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/10/full-screen-keyboard-shortcut-mac-os-x/) article and pasted it here.  Basically, you create a keyboard shortcut to enter and exit the new Lion fullscreen App mode.

---

Open System Preferences and click on the`Keyboard` icon.

Select the `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab and choose `Application Shortcuts` from the list on the left.

Click on the `+` icon to add a new keyboard shortcut for all applications and type the following exactly:

`Enter Full Screen`

Now you need to assign it a keyboard shortcut, I chose <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> because it serves no purpose in OS X Lion, but it’s the old keyboard shortcut for entering into Front Row.

Click `Add` and then click on the `+` icon again, this time typing:

`Exit Full Screen`

Choose the same keyboard shortcut as you chose before, in this case <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, and click onto `Add` again.

Close out System Preferences.

Comment: Just tried this, and it didn't do anything.  Here is what my settings look like:  http://screencast.com/t/k6lxVEWq

Comment: Try changing the hotkeys.  I answered this while at work and not at a mac.  Just tried it on my Mac and didn't work with cmd+esc.  Tried ctl+cmd+F (as mentioned at the bottom of that linked page) and it worked.  Give that a shot.

Comment: Yes, now this is working for Safari, and I suspect other apps that can go into full screen mode, but doesn't affect Photoshop in any way.

Comment: I dug a little deeper and found this line on the adobe [site](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/known-issues-mac-os-10.html):  `Support for Mac OS 10.7 new features.  Mac OS 10.7 has some exciting new features such as Autosave, Restore, Versioning, Full Screen Mode, and more multi-touch gestures. For Adobe applications to fully support these features, additional product development is required. Adobe is working to address this issue. For related information, see Mac OSX 10.7 preference to "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" doesn't work with Adobe applications.`

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I'm not wording this correctly.  I don't think Photoshop has anything to do with "full screen mode".  The Photoshop panels "stick" to the desktop, so the file window can be moved around, but the panels remain where they are.  I want all of those panels to be contained inside the window as well.  Like it used to be.

Comment: Ah, I understand.